# Conjugate prior for the gaussian distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, conjugate-prior

Let a set of random observations $\{X_i\}$, such that $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Suppose that the mean $\mu$ and the variance $\sigma^2$ both are unknown.

What is the conjugate prior for the unknown $\mu$ if we want it to be always positive? For the variance, we can choose a $Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ distribution. Can we choose the same for the mean?

Comment: You would not use a Gamma distribution for the variance but either a Gamma distribution for the inverse of the variance or an inverse Gamma for the variance.

Comment: You can use a truncated normal distribution for the mean

Comment: Thank you @Henry for your reply. The variance is positive, so why we can't use a Gamma distribution for it ? is that for convenience of conjugacy?

Comment: You can use whatever you like, but only some families of distributions will be conjugate

Comment: For the mean, the idea is to use a prior distribution that allows constraining the likelihood to be positive, so for that reason I am asking if that possible. Now, I know that in order to get a closed-form solution for the posterior distribution, we should use conjugate distributions only. But what if we don’t get a close form solution but instead we get a formula that we can’t write as any other known distribution?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to look at this in a more general way. So you have a Bayesian model with a likelihood function $L_x(\theta)$ and a prior $\pi(\theta)$, say.
Then the posterior is proportional to $L_x(\theta) \cdot \pi(\theta)$. Now you modify the prior by incorporating the knowledge that $\theta$ is positive, so the new prior is $\pi(\theta) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\theta>0}$, renormalized by dividing by the probability that $\theta >0$. Let us write this new prior as $\pi_A(\theta)\propto \pi(\theta)\cdot \mathbb{1}_A(\theta)$, which is simply the prior $\pi$ restricted to the set $A$.

This gives a new posterior, also restricted to the set $A$, which is proportional to
$$ \pi_A(\theta \mid x) \propto L_x(\theta)\cdot \pi(\theta)\cdot \mathbb{1}_A(\theta)
$$ which simply is the old posterior restricted to the set $A$. So the only thing you need to do is recompute the constant of proportionality.

So, in your case, if the posterior without restriction is a normal density, then with the restriction to the positive axis it will be a truncated normal.

If you also have a conjugate prior for the variance, then the marginal posterior for the expectation will be a t distribution, the restricted posterior will be a truncated t distribution.